# How to get the list of dependencies via IntelliJ open api

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, openapi

I'm developing a plugin for IntelliJ IDE and I want to show the dependencies that belongs to the current project.
Is there is a way to get the list of dependencies via IntelliJ open api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each module in your project, you can use `ModuleRootManager` to get the dependencies:

```
// get the modules on which it depends
ModuleRootManager.getInstance(module).getDependencies()

// get the libraries on which it depends
ModuleRootManager.getInstance(module).getModifiableModel().getModuleLibraryTable()
```